# file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in telegram.php on line 49

Tags: bots, telegram

I use this code in index.php page

```
function get_model_info($model)
        {
           $query="select * from mobile where model_name='".$model."' limit 1";

              return $query;

              }
        // $telegram = null;
        $query=get_model_info($text);
        $telegram->query=$query;
         $telegram->runqury();
         $result=$telegram->queryresult;
         $text=urlencode($result->fetch_object()->info);

     $telegram->sendmessage($userid, $text);
```

and used this code on telegram.php page

```
public function sendmessage($userid,$text)
  {
    $url='https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$this->token.'/sendmessage?chat_id='.$userid.'&text='.$text;
       file_get_contents($url);
     }
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

sending text messages to telegram chat using php must be like bellow:

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken."/sendMessage?chat_id=@yourtargetID&text=yourText";
file_get_contents($url);
```

You must replace `sendmessage?` with `sendMessage?` (Capital M)